# Update all cells of a datatable in one go in c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have situation, I need my DataRows (string columns) to be HTMLEncoded. Can we update entire cells of a DataRow in one go using LINQ or any other way?

Basically I want to avoid loops.

I have a datatable oDt.
DataTable have following columns : id_season, season, modifiedon(date);

To save this dataTable i have a function

```
Save Table(DataTable oDT){
    //Here I have to update modifedon column to DateTime.now;
     foreach(datarow dr in oDT.Rows)
     {
               dr[modifiedon] = DateTime.now;
     }
    // I need to avoid this loop as datatable can have 35000 + records
}
```

Comment: please add your code snippet to get help by community

Comment: You have some possibilities. My guess would be: create an extension method on DataRowCollection (or DataTable) to alter the data. A bit of code would be helpful though.

Comment: Is your DataTable bound to a DataSource?

Comment: @Xpanse No, DataTable is not bound to DataSource.

Comment: I see no reason why looping through 35000 rows in a DataTable would be a performance problem. If it was bound to a datasource it might. Any LINQ or extension methods would invariably have to loop somewhere in the logic process. This isn't something you will be able to get around.

Comment: If you are concerned about potential performance issues it might be worth running some tests to see how long the execution might take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must update every element, so you are are looking at O(n) time regardless.
On my system, updating 35,000 elements takes between 0.01 and 0.03 seconds, 350,000 items takes .1 to .3 seconds, etc. You can get a small performance boost by getting the value of DateTime.Now outside the loop like this:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
foreach(DataRow dr in oDT.Rows)
{
    dr["ModifiedOn"] = now;
}
```